# Style paragraph with a specific class inside a div

Tags: html, css

I know this is extremely easy, but I am stuck right now and cannot make it work. How can I give only to the paragraph that has the  class "text-muted" to have color:#ff9;
I used the class "text-muted" in some others elements that have black color but I do not want them to change.

I can add inline style inside and it had worked but I don't want to do in this way.Here is the code:

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-img"><img src="" alt="picture"></div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">blabla bla</h4>
    <hr>
    <p class="text-muted">blabla bla!</p>
    <div class="card-btn"><a href="blog.html" class="btn btn-
  primary">more</a></div>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Add the code to your question, so it is nicely formatted.

Comment: I imagine you have tried `.text-muted {color:#ff9}` ;). If you have, then try `.card .text-muted {color:#ff9}` to give it higher presidency over styles that might be overriding it. If that doesn't work, inspect the element using the browsers developer console to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, so easy, it worked!

Comment: No problem. Accept alexia-constantinou answer, because he did a proper answer and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

To style a particular element type that has a particular class combine them in your css selector:

```
p.text-muted {
    color: #ff9;
}
```

This is saying "Apply the text color of `#ff9` to any `p` tag that has a class of `text-muted`"

**edit after question clarification**

to apply this colour only to elements that are inside a particular element (`.card-block`) use:

```
.card-block p.text-muted {
    color: #ff9;
}
```

or if you know the p tag will be a direct child of the parent element:

```
.card-block > p.text-muted {
    color: #ff9;
}
```

Comment: This will change all p with class text-muted. My question is that I want to change only the p inside the specific divs.

Comment: which specific div?

Comment: <div class="card-block">

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below in css :

```
p.center {
text-align: center;
color: red;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the p inside the specific divs, do as follow:

```
div.card-block > p {
    /* your css ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
.card-block .text-muted{
    color:#ff9;
}
```